# Clear "view history" on YouTube

Tags: youtube

With the new video recommendation system YouTube offers, I could not find a way to clear off my history. This is frustrating because it shows "because you watched X" we recommend this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[YouTube Help](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57714) has a solution on this.

> To clear your viewing history, follow
>   the steps below:
>
> 1. Sign into [your account](http://youtube.com/my_account), and click the [account](http://www.youtube.com/account) link at the top
>      right of the page.
> 2. Under "**My Videos**" click the [History](http://www.youtube.com/account) option.
> 3. Click the "Viewing History" tab in the gray bar to see videos you
>      viewed since you opened your browser.
> 4. To clear it, click the "**Clear Viewing History**" button at the top of
>      the video list.
>
> Go directly to your [Viewing History](http://youtube.com/recently_watched).
>
> When **searching for videos** on the site,
>   you can turn off **search suggestions** as
>   you type your query into the search
>   bar. Please follow these tips to turn
>   off search suggestions as you type:
>
> 1. Type your search query into the search bar at the top of the page.
>      Click the "search" button.
> 2. On the right hand side of the page, click on *advanced options*.
> 3. A window will appear. Deselect "Display query suggestions as I type".
>      You have now opted to turn off the
>      search query suggestions.
> 4. Finally, click the "search" or "close" button on the window to exit
>      the "advanced options" window (and
>      return to the page you were on
>      before).